# Bash to python convertion for sending email

Tags: bash, python-2.7, email, subprocess

I am converting a shell script to python. In my python code , when i tried to send email , i am getting error message.I am new to python. Please help me on solving this.

***Shell code:***

```
id=`whoami`

userid_list=2nd_user

SUBJECT=mail

echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

From: $id

To: $userid_list

Subject: $SUBJECT
" > $email

SENDMAIL=/usr/lib/sendmail

$SENDMAIL -oi -t < $email
```

***python code :***

```
sender_id = getpass.getuser()

userid = getpass.getuser()

content  = """Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

            From: """ + sender__id + """

            To: """ + userid + """

            Subject: mail"""

email= "/tmp/mail"

with open(email, 'a') as f:

    f.write(content)

SENDMAIL = "/usr/lib/sendmail"

subprocess.call(SENDMAIL + " -oi -t < " + email, shell=True)
```

***Error message:***

sendmail: fatal: vijay(1254164854): No recipient addresses found in message header

Comment: In shell code, with same users(sender & receiver mail id), it works fine

Comment: I hope that it's just a typo, but your `sender__id` in your content variable has two underscores instead of the original declared `sender_id` which only has one.

Comment: @James Joyce Alano. Yes it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you check what it writes in `/tmp/mail`? Maybe that could be a hint.

Comment: @Learner Glad to be of help. Can I post it as an official answer?

Comment: @chw1. Now it worked fine. i made a mistake in variable used.

Comment: @James Joyce Alano. Yes please.  I tried it in interpreter mode. I will once via my python script

Comment: @James Joyce Alano. Actually, I tired the subprocess command with email file created by shell code. So it works fine at that time.  Now , again i am getting the same error , after the the variable name(sender_id) also.

Comment: @chw1. yes. problem might be with email file(/tmp/mail)

Comment: Line alignment of two mail files(1 from shell & 1 form python) are different. i maually changed the alignment . It is woking. Need to chage the alignment via python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line alignment of two mail files(1 from shell & 1 form python) are different.When i changed the alignment, it worked.

**email file from shell:**

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

```
                   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

From: vijay

To:  kumar

Subject: test mail

**email file("/tmp/mail") from python:**

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

```
                   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
                   From: vijay
                   To:  kumar
                   Subject: test mail
```

I changed the alignment of email file(generated from python code) as shell.It worked

Answer (score 0):

The `sender__id` in your content variable has two underscores instead of the original declared `sender_id` which only has one.

Python treats each variable as an object and each variable doesn't need to be declared for it to be used, so the compiler/interpreter will not warn you if it encounters situations such as the one you posted.